# Firebase template domain verification and firebase hosting at the same time seems to fail

Tags: dns, firebase-hosting, namecheap

I'm after having associated a custom domain for firebase hosting and firebase dynamic links, I was trying to setup a custom domain for authentificatio email templates. However verification for the authentification fail.

I'm using Namecheap for the DNS configuration.

Is it because the cname and @ directive conflict one with each other ? I chose a subdomain for the authentification template mail:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information is DNS servers is public information. Trying to answer what is wrong is very hard when you hide the information required.

1. Go to [Google Domains](https://domains.google.com/)  Is your domain verified in Google Domains? If not complete that step first.
2. The CNAME resource records appear correct.
3. Most likely the last two TXT records are wrong. I am guessing that you are using something like **app.example.com**. The managed zone is **example.com**. The host is **app**. Your TXT records should only have **app* without the managed zone **example.com**.
4. After you modify DNS server resource records be prepared to **wait**. Firebase will say up to 48 hours.
5. If my answer does not solve your problem you will either need to disclose your DNS server resource records or find someone that understands DNS to help you.

Comment: Sorry I've hidden the information out of a reflex because I always do on any screenshot. Thanks for the tip! I'll try to remove the .example.app and get back to you in 48h :-)
By the way, it's the firebase instructions which are ambiguous because they indeed keep it in the table of records to be added.

Comment: @gbaccetta - Each DNS provider uses different methods. There are also different ways of specifying the host entry. The documentation assumes that you understand DNS and would know how to configure A, CNAME, and TXT resource records for your DNS server. In reality, DNS requires a fair amount of experience to manage correctly.

Comment: Thanks, that finally worked. Though I had to modify also something that does not appear in y screenshots. Firebase also suggest to add this CNAME:
`firebase1._domainkey.app.example.com` and
`firebase2._domainkey.app.example.com` - 
I also had to remove `example.com` from those cname host values, following your line of thought. Sorry for the late reply. I was on holiday

Comment: @JohnHanley Hello, I am using Cloudflare, but I'm sure it has similar settings to Namecheap. With Cloudflare, I have everything routed through a proxy and supposedly, it only works with the "DNS setting" only... Do you happen to know anything about this?

Comment: @jeff Please do not ask questions in the coments. Post a new question. If you let me know the link, I will try to help.